# How come outlook adds "ecx" on html classes in emails? How to fix?

Tags: outlook

When creating classes in emails and sending the email to outlook, it adds "ecx" to the beginning of your created class:

< a class="social">
 Lorem ipsum....
< /a>

in Outlook:
< a class="ecxsocial" >
 Lorem ipsum....
< /a>

I'm trying to figure out why this is happening and how to fix the issue.

I'm currently adding classes to < a> tags which has a nested image.

Answer (score 0):

This article only talks about line height, but the fix may be similar for you. You can write your own ".ExternalClass" or "ecxClass" CSS rules to overwrite some of what they're doing.

http://www.emailonacid.com/blog/details/C13/line_height_and_outlook.com

I found out that Outlook.com wraps all your html in a div with class="ExternalClass" to adjust line height to what it wants. Then it precedes all your classes and ids with "ecx" and applies its own CSS to your code. The article below claims Outlook.com tries really hard not to mess with your CSS... but we're here now aren't we? :)